topology effect on PDE solution
I'm interested in understanding how the topology of a domain influences the solutions of a PDE defined on that domain. Specifically, I'm curious if there are methods to explore different topological configurations of the domain to find an optimal solution to the PDE, such as one that satisfies certain desired properties. Could you point me to mathematical concepts and areas of study that address this topic? Additionally, as I'm relatively new to this field, I would appreciate recommendations for introductory references to help build my background. Thank you!

Even in the simplest case, where we want to solve the PDE
$$
\nabla u=f
$$
on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ for a given $f \in C_c(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$, you can see how topology affect this problem. In this case, if $\Omega$ is not simply connected, there might exists a $f$, which is not conservative, i.e. the integral
$$
\int_{\gamma}fds\neq 0
$$
does not vanish for some curve $\gamma \subset \Omega$ and therefore $f$ cannot be gradient field.
Now the smoothness of your domain can dictate the smoothness of your solution. A lot of regularity results for, say Poisson equation
$$
\Delta u=f
$$
only hold for domains with regular (usually Lipschitz) boundaries. In some of the other cases, you don't have smoothness up to the boundary. So the differential topology of your domain affects the solution to the PDE.
More is true if you look for PDEs defined on manifold, here the space of solution can entirely depend on properties of the manifold, usually some sign of a curvature tensor. It can even be empty in some cases!
I would recommend starting with Evans PDE book to see how the standard cases are handled. From there, pick a topic you love to explore! If you are interested in manifolds, I can recommend Josts textbook on these topics.

Thanks for reply! Do you think geometric analysis is the most relevant field?

The most relevant field as in "a good area of research to get into" or a "good area to study to answer your question"?

I'm not familiar with the concept I mentioned in my question above. It just came to mind. Therefore, I want to study and build my background, and maybe start my research in this area in the future. So yes, I'm looking for the area of math to study.

I would highly recommend taking at least 1 PDE class (or self-study the equivalent). If you like what you saw there, consider taking more classes or study more. Geometric PDE is a really wild, wild topic and I can only recommend Josts textbook as a starting point.
Even in differential geometry, a lot of proofs are PDE-based or Calculus of Variations based (the Nash embedding theorem being the most famous example). So it is worth studying!

As for area of research to get into: I think it is a difficult but rewarding subject to study the connections between PDE and topology. If you continue down this path, you will find moduli spaces based on PDE solutions giving rise to invariants of manifolds.
It is your choice!

Thank you so much!

You are welcome! Good luck on your quest!
